# SignalR sending javascript commands from server

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

I saw a nice demo on using SignalR to push response to client here:
http://blog.webdevsamples.com/web-forms-long-running-task-with-progress-bar-using-signalr

The problem I am facing is, I want to be able to update the progress from the server end, whereas this demo launches the progress bar as soon as the page is loaded.

Can anyone help me configure this demo such that when you click on a button, the progress bar launches?

Comment: So I was able to trigger the javascript command via 
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, sender.GetType(), "UpdateProgressBar2", "showProgress(50,\"abc\")", true); But this is not ideal

Comment: Okay? Did that fix your problem? Why is it not ideal?

Comment: Because this is not using SignalR's push capability. I was only able to trigger a page update by registering new javascript command. How would you do it in a SignalR context?

Comment: Usually you do that from a hub. It sounds like you need to check out some of the [basic demos](http://www.asp.net/signalr). Then try to implement something. Then if you get stuck, point out how your implementation doesn't do what you want.

Comment: I'm curious as to why this question is getting upvoted.  It is certainly not a well-formed question by SO standards